# How to fix text on React Navigation createMaterialTopTabNavigator text in menu issue

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

For some reason my text on the tab menu does not fix correctly on small screen Can someone help with this. It only happens with devices with smaller screens

```
<Tab.Navigator
        tabBarOptions={{
          tabStyle: {
            height: '100%',
            // padding: this.state.width < 340 ? '5%' : null,
            color: 'grey',
          },
          labelStyle: {
            // fontSize: this.state.width < 340 ? 12 : null,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          },
          style: {
            backgroundColor: this.props.theme.colors.NavTabBar,
          },
        }}
        numberOfLines={1}
        swipeEnabled={false}
        lazy={true}
        lazyPlaceholder={() => <ActivityIndicator />}>
        <Tab.Screen name="Shows" component={SceneOverlayScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Listing" component={TabCameras} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Today" component={TabVideos} />
        <Tab.Screen name="New" component={TabSounds} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Contact" component={TabModes} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
```

[image]

Comment: Have a try with fontSize: 10 in labelStyle of tabBarOptions

Comment: hoping it would auto scale

Comment: Have a try to set properties in App.js on app startup to allowFontScaling to false.
Text.defaultProps = Text.defaultProps || {};
Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;